# Postprocess row with pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I am trying to surround all elements in a specific table row with square brackets, using `postproc cell content` in `pgfplotstable`.

As shown in the MWE, it works well for processing a column, but not for a row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,
    every first row/.append style={postproc cell content/.append style={/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={[}{]}}},
    columns/B/.append style={postproc cell content/.append style={/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={[}{]}}},
]{
    A B C
    m s kg
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I had expected to see all elements in the second row (`every first row`) as well as in column `B` surrounded by square brackets.

Does `postproc cell content` not work on a per row basis?

Answer (score 3):

A question which reveals an unclear definition in `pgfplotstable`. A look into its source code confirms that `postproc cell content` is only applicable in the context where column styles are evaluated.

This is either a missing feature or at least something which needs to be clarified in the manual. Probably the first.

In the meantime, you can use `every row <index> column <name>` which *supports* `postproc cell content`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,
    brackets/.style={
        postproc cell content/.append style={/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\relax[}{]}},
    },
    every row 0 column A/.append style={brackets},
    %every row 0 column B/.append style={brackets},
    every row 0 column C/.append style={brackets},
    columns/B/.append style={brackets},
]{
    A B C
    m s kg
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I took the freedom to define a separate style for your brackets.

Note the `\relax`: it turns out that `pgfplotstable` works well without it, but `tabular` does not: it assumes that the brackets are associated with the preceding `\\`. To see this, add `debug` to your options and look into the log file.

Note that there is also `every row <index> column no <index>`.